# How can I install wsgi on CentOS using yum?

Tags: centos, mod-wsgi, wsgi

How can I install wsgi on CentOS using yum? Is there any repository with mod_wsgi?

Comment: I already switched to Ubuntu, this being only one many reasons. Still I will accept the best answer, if it will not include compilation, not because I cannot do it just because it's not good for maintenance.

Comment: To find out if mod_wsgi is already active, `httpd -M`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fedora EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)

Answer (score 18):

```
yum install mod_wsgi
```

confirmed on CentOS 5.7

Answer (score 0):

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnLinux#RHEL/Centos_Packages

There is lots of other useful documentation on the mod_wsgi site as well. ;-)